# How do I set the contents of a CALayer to a CGImageRef?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I want to set the contents of a `CALayer` to an image. The `CALayer` has a `contents` property The documentation on that property says that *"a layer can set this property to a CGImageRef to display the image as its contents."* But the property takes an `id` so in Xcode I get the following issue:

> Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer
>   types assigning to 'id' from
>   'CGImageRef' (aka 'struct CGImage *')

How can I assign a `CGImageRef` to the `contents` property when it only takes an `id`? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explicitly casting `CGImageRef` to `id` should fix the warning. For example,

```
CGImageRef imageRef;

...

layer.contents = (id) imageRef;
```

should be working fine.

Comment: Bingo. I don't entirely understand why though. `CGImageRef` isn't an `NSObject` and therefore can't be represented as an `id`... right? What's actually happening in this cast?

Comment: @SimonCave Casting to `id` cost nothing at runtime. Actually, the compiled binary should even look the same with or without casting. The point is that the document told us we can set `CGImageRef` to `contents`, so we just blindly believe it. The internal implementation might actually just cast it back to `CGImageRef` if it's the only valid type for the `contents` according to the documentation.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using (id) you can use (__bridge id) to solve the type convert issue.

Comment: +1 jerry.  i found that a simple (id) cast did not work but your suggestion did.  is it because i'm using c++11?