# High-performance copying of RGB pixel data to the screen in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-graphics, core-video

Our product contains a kind of software image decoder that essentially produces full-frame pixel data that needs to be rapidly copied the screen (we're running on iOS).

Currently we're using CGBitmapContextCreate and we access the memory buffer directly, then for each frame we call CGBitmapContextCreateImage, and then draw that bitmap to the screen. This is WAY too slow for full-screen refreshes on the iPad's retina display at a decent framerate (but it was okay for non-Retina-devices).

We've tried all kinds of OpenGL ES-based approaches, including the use of glTexImage2D and glTexSubImage2D (essentially rendering to a texture), but CPU usage is still high and we can't get more than ~30 FPS for full-screen refreshes on the iPad 3. The problem is that with 30 FPS, CPU usage is nearly at %100 just for copying the pixels to the screen, which means we don't have much to work with for our own rendering on the CPU.

We are open to using OpenGL or any iOS API that would give us maximum performance. The pixel data is formatted as a 32-bit-per-pixel RGBA data but we have some flexibility there...

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you use Instruments to see exactly what operation is using all your CPU? I have done something similar and found a lot of time was spend converting RGBA to ARGB (not saying that's your issue but it might help to see a profile, if you haven't done that yet)

Comment: What exactly does "draw that bitmap to the screen" mean? Are you drawing in a UIView's `-drawRect:` method, or putting the CGImage in a layer, or using a UIImageView? The two latter methods should be significantly faster -- see this [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410106/drawing-image-with-coregraphics-on-retina-ipad-is-slow/10424635#10424635).

Comment: What was your "glTexSubImage2D" approach? I believe this should be quick enough if done correctly.. How I understand what you are doing is you process raw pixel data on CPU and push those data to GPU and render them. That is maximum of about 4kx4kx4B (64MB) of data being pushed for a whole texture (for iPad3) and doesn't seem too much.. Anyway, if in any case this is what causes the drop in fps, I don't see any better way then working directly on the GPU with the pixels.

Answer (score 2):

So, the bad news is that you have run into a really hard problem. I have been doing quite a lot of research in this specific area and currently the only way that you can actually blit a framebuffer that is the size of the full screen at 2x is to use the h.264 decoder. There are quite a few nice tricks that can be done with OpenGL once you have image data already decoded into actual memory (take a look at GPUImage). But, the big problem is not how to move the pixels from live memory onto the screen. The real issue is how to move the pixels from the encoded form on disk into live memory. One can use file mapped memory to hold the pixels on disk, but the IO subsystem is not fast enough to be able to swap out enough pages to make it possible to stream 2x full screen size images from mapped memory. This used to work great with 1x full screen sizes, but now the 2x size screens are actually 4x the amount of memory and the hardware just cannot keep up. You could also try to store frames on disk in a more compressed format, like PNG. But, then decoding the compressed format changes the problem from IO bound to CPU bound and you are still stuck. Please have a look at my blog post [opengl_write_texture_cache](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post12_opengl_write_texture_cache/index.html) for the full source code and timing results I found with that approach. If you have a very specific format that you can limit the input image data to (like an 8 bit table), then you could use the GPU to blit 8 bit data as 32BPP pixels via a shader, as shown in this example xcode project [opengl_color_cycle](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post11_opengl_color_cycle/index.html). But, my advice would be to look at how you could make use of the h.264 decoder since it is actually able to decode that much data in hardware and no other approaches are likely to give you the kind of results you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

After several years, and several different situations where I ran into this need, I've decided to implement a basic "[pixel viewer](https://github.com/eldoogy/EEPixelViewer)" view for iOS. It supports highly optimized display of a pixel buffer in a wide variety of formats, including 32-bpp RGBA, 24-bpp RGB, and several YpCbCr formats.

It also supports all of the UIViewContentMode* for smart scaling, scale to fit/fill, etc.

The code is highly optimized (using OpenGL), and achieves excellent performance on even older iOS devices such as iPhone 5 or the original iPad Air. On those devices it achieves 60FPS on all pixel formats except for 24bpp formats, where it achieves around 30-50fps (I usually benchmark by showing a pixel buffer at the device's native resolution, so obviously an iPad has to push far more pixels than the iPhone 5).

Please check out [EEPixelViewer](https://github.com/eldoogy/EEPixelViewer).

Comment: I've been using this in a few projects and it is very easy to use.  It does seem to consume quite a bit of CPU though. On my iPhone 7Plus displaying a 1024x768 RGBA texture at 60fps used 30% of the CPU.  @Idoogy is this CPU usage pretty normal for copying that amount of data to the GPU each frame?

Answer (score 1):

CoreVideo is most likely the framework you should be looking at. With the OpenGL and CoreGraphics approaches, you're being hit hard by the cost of moving bitmap data from main memory onto GPU memory. This cost exists on desktops as well, but is especially painful on iPhones.

In this case, OpenGL won't net you much of a speed boost over CoreGraphics because the bottleneck is the texture data copy. OpenGL will get you a more efficient rendering pipeline, but the damage will have already been done by the texture copy.

So CoreVideo is the way to go. As I understand the framework, it exists to solve the very problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

The pbuffer or FBO can then be used as a texture map for further rendering by OpenGL ES. This is called Render to Texture or RTT. its much quicker search pbuffer or FBO in EGL

Comment: How would Render to Texture solve this problem? We're looking to take existing bits from the CPU and get them over to the screen. Our rendering is done by the CPU, not by the GPU.

Comment: UIImage is fastest to access from CPU in IOS according to me

Comment: @talktomevintron - No, it most definitely is not. There's significant Core Graphics overhead in extracting raw pixel data from a UIImage in my benchmarks. You're much better off in working with raw pixel data in some other format.