# UIView animations fine in simulator, choppy on device

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview

I three UIView animations in my app. One to move in a view (similar to the appearance of a modalViewController presentation), another to move it out, and a third to set the frame of a UIImageView. On the simulator, it looks great; smooth and clear. However, on an actual device (iPhone 4) it's very choppy and sometimes doesn't animate at all. On my iPad 2, it looks a little better, however not where it should be. Any clue what's wrong?

Comment: Look at my answer here on image animation performance http://stackoverflow.com/a/12327075/1378694

Comment: Could you post your code? Also @bbodayle's link is great

Comment: Thanks for that link, it could be that I have shadows and rounded corners as all the elements I am animating have both of those effects. What do you recommend to fix this?

Comment: Okay, figured it out... If I delete all of the '.layer' code (no shadows, no rounded corners) it looks great. However, I want these features in my app, how can I get both?!?

Comment: Set your layer's `shouldRasterize` property to `YES`

Comment: When I use shouldRasterize on a UIButton, the button's image is very pixelated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it- for future reference, iOS isn't great at programatic drop shadows... If it's a rectangular view you're using, you can use "View.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:View.bounds].CGPath;"